# how do I use this pycrypto code in pycryptodome

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, pycryptodome

how do I use this pycrypto code in pycryptodome:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

# the block size for the cipher object; must be 16 per FIPS-197
BLOCK_SIZE = 16

# the character used for padding--with a block cipher such as AES, the value
# you encrypt must be a multiple of BLOCK_SIZE in length.  This character is
# used to ensure that your value is always a multiple of BLOCK_SIZE
PADDING = '{'

# one-liner to sufficiently pad the text to be encrypted
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

# one-liners to encrypt/encode and decrypt/decode a string
# encrypt with AES, encode with base64
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

# generate a random secret key
secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

# create a cipher object using the random secret
cipher = AES.new(secret)

# encode a string
encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, 'password')
print 'Encrypted string:', encoded

# decode the encoded string
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
print 'Decrypted string:', decoded
```

Comment: Protip: If you need to post code so you can post a link, post the code from the link directly in the question.

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with the code? Does it throw an error? Does it produce incorrect output? You need to describe the problem. See also [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey This is a pycrypto code so it doesnt work with pycryptodome, but I want it to work with pycryptodome because I have to much trouble installing pycrypto

Comment: "... it doesnt work with pycryptodome...". Again, **how** doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you need to replace:

```
cipher = AES.new(secret)
```

with:

```
cipher = AES.new(secret, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

PyCryptodome is *almost* compatible with PyCrypto, with the exceptions of a few dangeours APIs (like leaving ECB as default encryption mode).